# Using AWS command line region different than S3 bucket location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the AWS command line to upload files to an S3 bucket located in the us-east-1 region.  I configured the command line to use the us-west-1 region since I am closer to that region.  I am able to upload and download files without specifying the same region.  The transfer speed is faster for me to use the command line with the us-west-1 region than the us-east-1 region.

Are there any issues with using a different region for the command line than the bucket location?  Are 'PUT' charges based on the bucket location or the command line location?  Will using a different region result in additional charges to "transfer" data to another region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is true that s3 buckets are based in regions, they are also global. You can access them from anywhere without any problems as long as you have the correct permissions to them.

I doesn't matter where you upload stuff from(`PUT`) what matters is where the bucket location is when it comes to [price](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/). There are no extra charges if you upload stuff from another region, however, for obvious reasons it will be slower to upload large files from another region than it would be if you were in the same region.

Answer (score 0):

There's no charge for transfer into S3 over the public internet, period. Regardless of S3 region.

Note that if you specifically want to transfer data from the west coast into S3 in us-east-1 and you're not happy with the performance over the public internet (at no charge) then take a look at [S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) ($0.04/GB) which uses CDN edge locations to terminate your upload closer to you and then transfers the data to S3 from there.